# Add a method to prototype of js object

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, addition

Trying to add a method to js `Date` object to get formatted date, `Date` is not declared anywhere or called with `new`/`create()`:

```
Date.prototype.format = function () {
       // return this.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + this.getDate()).slice(-2)
       var curr_date = this.getDate();

    var curr_month = this.getMonth() + 1;

    var curr_year = this.getFullYear();

    return curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;
    }
```

I've messed up with `this` variable.
`getDate()`, `getMonth()`,`getFullYear()` are methods of `Date` object.

Error is thrown when`.getDate();` is called: `undefined is not a function`

**Please clarify how can I use other methods of single object type inside its prototype.**

Comment: Works for me: `new Date().format()` - `"2014-7-17"`

Comment: sorry then, it started working for me too.

Comment: This question should be closed because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Any chance you are calling this as an attribute rather than a method? I just put your code into Chrome's console, and it seems to work just fine, by calling it as a method.

```
new Date().format; // does not work

new Date().format(); // works
```

If you are still having troubles, consider rewriting it as a standalone function, rather than a prototype function.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use it without creating new instance of date... huh

You can do

```
 var d = new Date
```

in a function. and replace all THIS to d. Then you can do

```
Date.prototype.format()
```

But if you still want this, just do

```
new Date().format()
```